# Attach recipients using range from sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which lets me prepare an email which is ready to be sent:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Users").Range("A1").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Importance = 2
    .Subject = "[ACTION REQUIRED] Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")"
    .HTMLBody = "some_body"
    .Display
End With
```

and here is the Users table:

> **Users** 
>  Johnson, Jerry 
>  Mullen, Carl 
>  Mullen, Carl 
>  Mullen, Carl 
>  Terry, Mark 
>  Carlos, Juan

I need to create a macro which lets me prepare an email but my main problem is I don't know how to add recipients using data from Users table.
My current code is not allowing me to attach anything aside from string values (typed directly, or maybe I'm doing something wrong).
I also need it to not attach names that are duplicated.

Comment: Is the Users table located in an Excel worksheet?
Because if it is, you could loop through the range of users, add the names to a collection (To avoid duplicates), and then make a string of all the items in the collection, seperated by a ";". In the end .To should refer to this newly created string.

Comment: "not allowing me to attach anything" Do you need to add an attachment? If so you'll need to use `OutMail.Attachments.Add` See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names

Comment: @Alex4336  Yes this is what I want to happen, but since I just started vba a day ago, I'm still not sure on how to work on loops. Can you guide me as to what kind of loop and how to work with concatenating the ';' character in the said string result? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim although this was not the intended result I was hoping for, this helped me out for another task that I'm supposed to do after this, so thanks for the link bro!

Comment: I actually made a small example file, for exactly that, let me see if I saved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code assumes that you have your users' names in your outlook contact list, and that they are located in the cells A2 and down, but that range can be altered.

```
Sub test()
Dim users As New Collection
Dim usrRng As Range
Dim recipients As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set usrRng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In usrRng
    users.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
Next cell
On Error GoTo 0



For Each usrName In users
    recipients = recipients & usrName & "; "
Next usrName


With OutMail
    .To = recipients
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Importance = 2
    .Subject = "[ACTION REQUIRED] " & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    .HTMLBody = "some_body"
    .Display
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What this does, is that it takes each name in the range A2 and down, and adds it to a collection, skipping the duplicates.

Then we make a string, which will be made out of each name we just added to the collection, seperating each name with a ";".
Then we pass that new string to the OutMail object as the receiver of the message.

When the new mail is displayed, the names will not be recognized, but if press send, the mail should be sent to the correct people, assuming you don't have multiple contacts with the same name.

Comment: I'm gonna try this as soon as I get back to work tomorrow. I'll update you on how it works. Thank you so much for the response!