# Attaching variable file to VBA generated email

Tags: string, excel, vba, email-attachments

Thank you for all your help guys :) 
Code is now functioning.

I am still very new to VBA and am having some issues I would welcome advice on.

I have written some code so that dependent upon the value in a cell a varying email will be sent out to a particular person named in the sheet (each person will get one email). However, I would also like to attach a file specific to that person.

The file location will change weekly and the file name too as there is a date in the name.

The file location will be something like:

U:\My path\2016-08-08

and the file name

"Firstname Surname DD-MM-YYYY.xlsx"

(where Firstname Surname is earlier defined as "cell")

I came up with the following code (only relevant parts included):

```
   Dim DBlocation as variable
   Dim DBdate as variable
   Dim strfilename as string

   DBlocation = InputBox("Please copy file path to this week's dashboard files")
  DBdate = InputBox("Please type date from DB filename")

   strfilename = DBlocation & "\" & cell & " " & DBdate & ".xlsx" 

   .display
   .To = cell
   .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
   .Subject = cell & " Dashboard " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YY")
   .HTMLBody = strbody & vbNewLine & .HTMLBody

   .Attachments.Add (strfilename)
   .display
```

I have a textbox pop up with the filename and it looks right, but nothing is being attached to the email.

Could you advise how I should change the code to get the file attached?

Thank you so much in advance.

**UPDATE**

Code is now working as above.

I worked through your advice and made a couple of changes:

.Attachments.Add  - I added an S after Attachment

I also amended an earlier part of code that I didn't list above

```
   For Each cell In sh.Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

this was previously xlCellTypeConstants

I have no idea why this worked but it has :)
One super happy person here.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862085.aspx) will help...or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names).

Comment: @Brian the second link is where I got the code I started with (ie the idea to define as strlocation. The first I'm afraid I do not understand. There is a number of IF/ELSE queries which affect what is in the body of the email, and also whether the email even has an attachement (not all will). Is this example applicable in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

try adding "s" to attachment. Should look like **.attachments.add strFileName**

Comment: Isn't it case sensitive?

Comment: give breif description and provide what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

provided strfilename  is a valid file name

```
.Attachment.Add strfilename
```

Comment: Thanks - but still no attachment when I take the open and close brackets out.
I will add some additional questions above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt not knowing if your variables are valid:

```
Sub AttachFile()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim DBlocation As Variant 'Not "variable"
Dim DBdate As Variant 'Not "variable"
Dim strFileName As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'ActiveWorkbook.Path  <== Maybe use this instead if it is the same as "this week's dashboard files"?
DBlocation = InputBox("Please copy file path to this week's dashboard files")
DBdate = InputBox("Please type date from DB filename")

strFileName = DBlocation & "\" & cell & " " & DBdate & ".xlsx"

With OutMail
    .To = cell
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
    .Subject = cell & " Dashboard " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YY")
    .HTMLBody = strBody & vbNewLine & .HTMLBody
    .Attachment.Add strFileName
    .display
End With

End Sub
```

I would also strongly suggest that you use **Option Explicit** at the top of your module to make certain you have declared all your variables (i.e. `cell` and `strBody`).

Comment: thank you. I do have option explicit, just not copied in here.

I have now tried taking all the variants out and have just put in a valid filename in the .Attachment.Add and then the file name and still nothing is being attached. This makes me think the error is somewhere else?