# Sending attachments using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below code. It works find without the attachment line of code. But once I add the attachment line if get an error and can not work out how to correct it:

```
    Dim Email
Dim CC
Dim objOutlook    As Object
Dim objEmail      As Object
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

'Export report in same folder as db with date stamp
todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
fileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\XXDispute_" & todayDate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "XXDispute", acFormatPDF, fileName, False

strItem = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
strFrom = "XX Disputes <asd@asd.com>"

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With objEmail

    .To = "asd@asd.com"
    .CC = ""
    .From = strFrom
    .Subject = "XXDispute Report: " & Now()
    .Textbody = "Your XX dispute has been reviewed and responded to:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Attachments Add = fileName


With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item(strItem & "sendusing") = 2
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserver") = "mailhost"
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With
    .Send
End With
```

This is the particular line causing the problem:

```
    .Attachments Add = fileName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add attachement to outlook with varying file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names)

Comment: You should be able to see the faulty syntax of that line.