# Include attachment where the name matches recipient name

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have code in Excel which sends email to a list of recipients:

```
Sub SendEMail()
    Dim xEmail As String
    Dim xSubj As String
    Dim xMsg As String
    Dim xURL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Double
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "Send emails to:", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg.Columns.Count <> 3 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect number of columns: You have to choose Name, Email address, Account no.!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
    '   Get the email address
        xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 2)
    '   Message subject
        xSubj = "Your customer's account is on hold"
    '   Compose the message
        xMsg = ""
        xMsg = xMsg & "Dear client" & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "We would like to inform you, that Your account has been put on hold - "
        xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(i, 3).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "If you have any queries, please contact us on uk.ar@bodycote.com." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "Kind regards," & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "Jon and Martina"
    '   Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
    '   Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
    '   Create the URL
        xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
    '   Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
    '   Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    Next
End Sub
```

I would like to add variable attachments. It will be a pdf file and its name will be the same as the name of customer (which is placed in column A). Basically it should look for "Name.pdf" in "S:\All Team\AX OTI\test\"

The source table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you have something that works really nicely - [Add attachement to outlook with varying file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names)

In your case, simply copy the code and make sure that in the part `strLocation` you write something like:

```
strLocation = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\" & Cells(i,2) & ".pdf"
```

thus, you will be able to loop around it. In general, take a good look at the mentioned answer, it is really a good approach (IMHO quite better than sending keys).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the below code.

```
        xMsg = xMsg & "Dear client" & xRg.Cells(i, 1)  & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 'Added the client Name (optional) you can remove it
        xMsg = xMsg & "We would like to inform you, that Your account has been put on hold - "
        xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(i, 3).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "If you have any queries, please contact us on uk.ar@bodycote.com." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & "Kind regards," & vbCrLf

        xMsg = xMsg & "Jon and Martina" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 'Added two break point

        '       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
        xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg &"&attachment=S:\All Team\AX OTI\test\" & Cells(i,1) & ".pdf" 'Changed to this
'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows me error msg **invalid qualifier** on this line `xMsg = xMsg & xMsg.Attachments.Add ("S:\All Team\AX OTI\test\" & Cells(i,1))  & ".pdf"`

Comment: `xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg &"&attachment=S:\All Team\AX OTI\test\" & Cells(i,1) & ".pdf"` use this and i have modified the code. Thanks

Comment: I've tried it, but the attachment is missing. The emails have been sent without no issues, just without attachments.

Comment: can you check the output and also share here in the immediate window for the `xURL` in the debug mode.

Comment: Why dont you try the `Email object` to do this task. That is much more easier than this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Vityata advice, I've checked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names) and based on that, I' ve changed the code. **It is tested and works smoothly**. The code is much easier, but the job is done.

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Variant


 With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'list of recipients (email address) - it takes as many addresses as B column contains
    End With

For i = 2 To lastrow

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With OutApp
    .Subject = "Your customer's account is on hold"
    .Body = "Dear client" & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "We would like to inform you, that Your account has been put on hold." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "If you have any queries, please contact us on uk.ar@bodycote.com." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kind regards," & vbCrLf & "Jon and Martina"
    .To = Cells(i, 2).Value
     strLocation = "S:\All team\AX OTI\test\" & Cells(i, 1) & ".pdf"
    .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
    .display
    '.send
    End With

Next i

debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```